# If image height exceeds image width, vertically center image by cropping its top and bottom - possible with only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given a scenario where you don't know the height and width of image elements in advance, let's say that in cases where image height is greater than image width, you'd like to vertically center the image by cropping the same amount of pixels form its top and bottom, such that the new image height matches the image width. For example, if an image has a width of 200px, and its height is 250px, crop 25px from its top and from its bottom.

Here's an example setup:

HTML:

```
<div class = 'cell'>
  ...
  <div class = 'image_container'> 
     ... 
     <img ...> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    /* width will be changed by use of '@media screen'.
       Smaller browser window -> larger width */
    width: 31%;
}

.image_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.image_container > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish the aforementioned center/crop operation using only CSS, or is it necessary to use javascript/jquery for this?

Comment: In CSS you have available `object-fit:` which basically allows you to do similar stuff like `background-size:` does, and that's assigning `contain` or `cover` values, but **none of those seem to fit your requirement** description. At least it's totally unclear what you mean by *`"and crop the same amount of height from the top and bottom of the image"`* given you didn't specified any height. Cropping is achieved using `cover` (cause `contain` does not crops), but than the image is not "centered" but rather ***covers*** the entire designated area..

Comment: Do you have a given width and/or height an image should fit?

Comment: @LGSon - The images are inside of grid cells (filling up 100% of the width of each cell), which are arranged by packery. There can be 3, 2, or 1 grid cells in a row, depending on the width of the browser window, and a row takes up 100% of the width of the grid. Those are the only constraints on the image width, and the height should be constrained by the image width.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - 'given you didn't specified any height' - I specified that the height should not exceed the width. "Crop the same amount of height" means that if image width is 200px, and the image's actual height is 250px, you crop 25px from the top and bottom of the image. Sorry - I could have been clearer in my description. I'll edit it.

Comment: crop and not shrink?

Comment: @repzero - by "crop," I mean chop off the content that's present in certain areas.

Comment: The container needs to know the image's width to be able to do what you want. If the `transform: rotate(90deg)` would have affected its bounding square that would been a trick to pull, in combination with `background-size: cover`, but since it doesn't, you'll need a script to get that value

Comment: But then again, since you will load many images, most likely they will have different width's, which will cause new problems giving different height's, so with that scenario you'll have to choose if to go with the widest or ....  I recommend you pick a certain height based on available width, columns wanted, and use `@media` queries and `background-size: cover` to make it look good

Comment: @LGSon - the width will be made proportional to browser window size. To clarify, I've edited the code in the question.

Comment: Yeah, but you said its height should be the image's width and then if image height was higher it should crop to its width .. or no?

Comment: @LGSon - For each image, if the image's height exceeds image width (as displayed on screen), the image should be cropped.

Comment: Exactly, so if you reread my above comments with that in mind, does they make sense? ...What I am saying is you should give the container a predefined height matching its width and then have the images cropped to fit

Comment: @LGSon - so you're saying that the height of the image should be bounded by height of the container, right? At that point, all one would need to do is vertically center the image. Thanks - that may be a viable approach. But taking the totality of the code into consideration, in my case, it would probably be a better idea to handle the cropping with javascript.

Comment: It might ... but performance wise, you will be better of using `background-size: cover` + fixed height on the container, which will crop either width or height, and make if fully filled ... and you can use viewport units `vw` / `vh` to make it proportional to the browser window

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS attribute. It acts a lot like the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) attribute.

```
.image_container > img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Note that this doesn't have full browser support as of now (October 2016) so you may want to look into setting the image as a background on a div and using `background-position` and `background-size` to deal with this instead of an `<img>` tag.

```css
.image_container {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  image-rendering: pixelated;

  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAALklEQVQoU2NkgID/UBqdYmSESoJobOA/sgKQKTCFMDaKAuqYAHMs3CqiHInXmwDZGBMDEmk6SQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I wasn't aware of the `object-fit` property. However, I'm trying it out in the latest Firefox and Vivaldi (Chrome) browsers, and it doesn't seem to have any effect. Are there any preconditions that have to be in place for this property to have an effect, or could it simply be an issue of lack of support? [Seems that it should be supported in Firefox by now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). The `background-*` solution variant sounds reasonable as well.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cover_image {
  height: 400px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/') no-repeat scroll center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover_image"></div>
```